# Where is the difference between Retain Counting and Reference Counting?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uikit

I feel that both are the same thing, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is a technique for resource management. In objective-c the *retain* method is used to increment the reference count so the terms reference count and retain count are interchangeable.

The [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011) provides a good overview.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing, they are synonymous:

- http://etoileos.com/dev/docs/languages/obj-c/

> ... An object has a reference count
>   (often called a retain count) and when
>   this reaches zero the object is sent a
>   dealloc message, which cause it to
>   free itself. At the simplest level,
>   every time you want to keep a pointer
>   to an object, you need to send it a
>   retain message: ...

- http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/04/the-secret-memory-management-tip-get-the-retain-count/

> ... When an app suddenly disappears
>   from the simulator it usually means
>   that the retain count (another name
>   for reference count) has gone to zero,
>   the system cleared it away but you
>   tried to access it! When you attempt
>   to send a message to a random bit of
>   memory that used to be your object
>   then - puff - you whole app just
>   disappears....

(I'm assuming you are just talking about the name and concept retain count, not the method retain)